# Mobile Antenna question

Tags: mobile-robot

I have a rocket-shaped (tube-shaped) mobile 20mm in diameter.  From a base-unit, 600yards away, I want to be able to send two floats (call it x and y) every 1/60th of a second (60Hz data rate [or faster]) to a pic chip such as the below pic chip that is inside the mobile.

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/40001723D-767332.pdf

For this I will need some type of antenna that will fit in the mobile.  You can assume there is line-of-sight between the fixed-base and the mobile with regard to communication-range.  The antenna will need to be able to communicate the (x,y) values to the pic chip.

Any suggestions on the antenna (and base communicator) for this?

I apologize in advance if this is a "shopping question."  (I don't have privileges to talk in the 'chat' section yet.)

If the correct term is 'receiver' instead of 'antenna', I also apologize in advance.

edit/add:  It seems a communication-delay of about 0.033seconds may be tolerable.  600yards = 548.64meters.

Comment: This sounds strange. Are you running a control-loop on the base station? And what is your maximal latency? 60Hz only describes the amount of data you send, but not how fast the data is sent to your rocket.

Comment: 2floats per 1/60second:  2/(1/60) = 120floats/sec.  FootheBar, it is 'like' command-signals being sent to an rc-plane, if that analogy helps.  If you want it in other units, it's a trivial conversion.

Comment: It seems a communication-delay of about 0.033seconds may be tolerable.  I have edit/add-ed that to the question-box.  600yd = 548.64meters.

Comment: Please *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)* @FooTheBar . For specific guidelines, see our [Code of Conduct](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Why did you remove the question about 2.4Ghz?

Comment: I don't recall having any Ghz values listed at any point.